# Comment error popup makes sidebar move down in review-beta

Tags: bug, design, css, review-beta

In review-beta, on Ask Ubuntu, if one creates a comment, clicks Edit, leaves it for ten minutes, and tries to save, they will get an error popup. However, this error popup causes the sidebar to jump downward until the popup is closed. This looks like a simple CSS issue, and has been tested in the First Posts area. I've also confirmed this simple bug in the close vote area. I've also been using a totally clean Firefox--no addons, userscripts, extensions, or plugins.

[image]